# Error using NameSpace.GetItemFromID with Outlook EntryID from Windows Search Index URL

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi, mailitem

When I extract an EntryID from Windows Search Index email items some of the EntryIDs always start with zeros eg

> 000000005559804AB84A6E49A3EBDF11D66E111724A33D00
>   000000005559804AB84A6E49A3EBDF11D66E111744A03D00

and I can supply call NameSpace.GetEntryFromID with the entryID as a single parameter and open the mail item

Where the EntryID does not start with zeros eg

> EF0000005DF0733903ACFB4A90E9F84DF839CED8A42D5300
>   EF0000005DF0733903ACFB4A90E9F84DF839CED824E75200

The emails come from a different mailbox and calling NameSpace.GetEntryFromID with these strings as a single parameter gives a Message Not Found error, presumably because the StoreID for the different Mailbox is not the default. Can I extract the StoreID from the EntryID strings returned from Windows Search URLs to pass as the second parameter for  GetEntryFromID?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the cause of the issue is not the store IDs. Each store have their own IDs. Even if you try to move items between stores in Outlook the EntryID property valued can be changed. Here is what MSDN states for the EntryID property:

> A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for a Microsoft Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The EntryID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file.

Anyway, if you do not specify the StoreID, GetItemFromID searches the default message store.

> Can I extract the StoreID from the EntryID strings returned from Windows Search URLs to pass as the second parameter for GetEntryFromID?

Nope. Instead, you can get the [Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff863655.aspx) object which is represented by the Folder class and use the [StoreID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867495.aspx) property.